# Want to increase the height of container div smoothly when an item is added to the list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried many times to do this but couldn't have done I must be missing something. So my problem is that I have a main div, it has a child div and the child div has an `<ol>`.
I have a search box where I search something and a function which add the a particular result to the `<ol>` when I click on it. Initially the display of the main div is `display:none;` and `height:auto;`.

As soon as I click on the search result the display of main div becomes `block` using JS and add an `li` item to `<ol>`. The problem here is that the height of main div increases suddenly when the item is added to `<ol>`. Same thing happens when I want to delete an item from added items.  but I want to increase and decrease it slowly.

You can checkout the sample code on codepen. link is https://codepen.io/sampat-28/pen/yLjwvEE

```
  <div class="search_results_container">
  <div class="search_results">
    <ol class="`added_list`" id="added_list"></ol>
  </div>

</div>
```

this is the html layout and CSS is mentioned below . I am new to css animations so please forgive me if i have made some mistakes.

```
.search_results_container{
  display: none;
  border: 4px solid #FFF;
  margin: 40px auto 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 21px;
  max-width: 850px;
  height:auto;
  width: auto;
}

.search_results{
 width:100%;
}

.added_list{
width:100%;
list-style-type:none;
height:auto;
height:100%;
}
```

Now there is a button on which if i click then it do two things If list is empty it makes display of `.search_results_container` to block and add a list item to it and this is the place where I am facing the problem. when I tried to add an animation to its height to increase slowly but it didn't worked. It increased the height equal to the list item's height  immediately when i added a list item. but I want it to increase its height smoothly both the time adding an element and deleting an element from the list
I need to use  as order of items is important.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the height change smoothly, you should be changing the height in the js instead of display.

Just give a transition to your search_results_container and it should work.

note: transition don't work on display.

Now the question is how to change the height dynamically as the content inside the container is changing.

The answer:

```
element.children[0].clientHeight
```

it gives the height of the first child of the element.

Here is the modified codepen link:

https://codepen.io/Starnas/pen/Rwyddex?editors=1111

There some changes in the css and the js. HTMl is untouched.

A piece of advice: declare your variables on the top of the file and use them in your code instead of query selectors everywhere that makes the code much cleaner.
If you still want to use the query selectors then make a function like:

```
function _(element){
   return document.querySelector(element);
}

//you can use it like this
_("#myDiv").style.height = "10px";
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to increase its height smoothly both the time adding an element and deleting an element from the list I need to use as order of items is important.

As you asked, to smoothly changing the height of element when adding/removing an item. It can be done with the combination of `CSS` and `JavaScript`.

In your case, I used `CSS` [animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) to change the height of each item when it is added/removed.

```
.added_list > li{
  animation: pop-in 1s both;
}

@keyframes pop-in {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }

  100% {
    height: 75px;
  }
}
```

When using `element.remove()` to removing an item from DOM it hides the element  immediately and there none of the animation are transition works. So, to remove an item smoothly as you ask, you can do some animation like hiding the element before using the `remove()` method. So, using JavaScript I added a class of "delete" to give the hiding the animation and then removed from DOM.

CSS:

```
.added_list li.delete {
  animation: pop-out 1s both;
}

@keyframes pop-out {
  0% {
    height: 75px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function removeListItem(e) {
  let container = e.parentNode;
  
  // Adding a class to giving the deleting animation
  container.classList.add("delete")

  setTimeout(() => {
  
    // After a '1s' removing the item from list
    container.remove()

    // Hiding the container when the item <1 which is 0
    if (list.children.length < 1) {
      searchContainer.style.display = "none";
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

After implementing this modifications your code may look like this:

```js
let num = 0;
const searchContainer = document.querySelector(".search_results_container")
const list = document.querySelector("#added_list");

document.querySelector(".add_btn").addEventListener('click', function() {
  let cont_display = searchContainer.style.display;
  if (cont_display == "" || cont_display == "none") {
    searchContainer.style.display = "flex";
  }

  const newShow = document.createElement("li");
  newShow.classList.add("addanim");
  var attr = document.createAttribute('draggable');
  attr.value = 'true';
  newShow.setAttributeNode(attr);
  newShow.classList.add("added_item_container");
  newShow.innerHTML = `<p>Item ${num} </p><i class="fa-regular fa-rectangle-xmark" onclick="removeListItem(this)"></i>`
  num++;
  list.prepend(newShow);
});

function removeListItem(e) {
  let container = e.parentNode;

  // Adding a class to giving the deleting animation
  container.classList.add("delete")

  setTimeout(() => {

    // After a '1s' removing the item from list
    container.remove()

    // Hiding the container when the item <1 which is 0
    if (list.children.length < 1) {
      searchContainer.style.display = "none";
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

```css
.search_results_container {
  display: none;
  border: 4px solid #FFF;
  margin: 40px auto 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 21px;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #333;
}

.search_results {
  width: 100%;
}

.add_item_div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.add_btn {
  height: 42px;
  border: none;
  background-color: limegreen;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.added_list {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

.added_list>li {
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  font-size: 28px;
  animation: pop-in 1s both;
}


/* Animation to smoothly increase the container height while adding item */

@keyframes pop-in {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
  }
}

.added_list li.delete {
  animation: pop-out 1s both;
}


/* Animation to smoothly decrease the container height and hide the item */

@keyframes pop-out {
  0% {
    height: 75px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.added_list li p {
  margin: 0;
}

.fa-rectangle-xmark {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
  text-rendering: auto;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 28px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background: #f80f0f;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 27px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 1px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search_results_container">
  <div class="search_results">
    <ol class="added_list" id="added_list">
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="add_item_div">
  <button class='add_btn'>Add an item</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer I exactly wanted the same. It means a lot to me. I will definitely up vote your answer once i get 15 points. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome buddy!. Yes with your reputation you can't but still you can accept the answer by selecting the check(✓) mark below the vote icons.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work?

```js
const ol = document.querySelector('ol');

const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
 const li = document.createElement('li');
 const text = document.createTextNode('carrort');
 li.appendChild(text);
 li.setAttribute('class', 'n')
 ol.appendChild(li);
})
```

```css
ol li {
height:30px;
margin-bottom:2px;

}
ol li.n {
 animation: inc 600ms linear;
 transform-origin:top;
 }
 
 @keyframes inc {
  from {
    opacity:0;
    transform:scale(1,0) translateY(-10px);
  } to {
    opacity:1;
    transform:scale(1,1) translateY(0px)
  }
 }
```

```html
<button>onAdd</button>
<ol>
 <li>carrort</li>
 <li>carrort</li>
 <li>carrort</li>
 <li>carrort</li>
 <li>carrort</li>
 <li>carrort</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: hi @Shiva thanks for your answer it is having the animation but cold not get properly. By the way I needed  animations like Kumara and Anas.